# Is there a way to change shadow-text size?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the size of the text-shadow?

This is what i want to achive:

[image: text with shadow effect]

If it's not, what do you recommend?

Comment: have you even tried researching this yourself? a quick search for css text shadow will bring up this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow.  And also a lot of text shadow generators

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of any effort on the OPs behalf

Comment: The only thing that may reffer to my problem is the blur-radius. It says: " the shadow becomes wider and lighter". But when I use it it doesn't change the size of the shadow - only make it more blurry. Am I missing sth?

Comment: In which case no it's not possible to do with text shadow, you would need to clone your text, upscale it and then position it absolutely behind your original adding some opacity to it

Comment: @Pete lack of effort does not mean that the question should be closed. Downvoted, maybe, but certainly not closed.

Comment: @StephenLeppik the first thing in the help center on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is Search and research. As this has not happened in this case, I voted to close it as off topic - I could have chosen that it is too broad as there are many ways to do what the OP is after but I thought I would show my fury at the lack of any effort.  After my comment, they've had a look and answered the first part of their question

Comment: @Pete You'll notice that there's an entirely separate page for the [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic). Not showing any research effort is not listed anywhere as off-topic.

Comment: @StephenLeppik read my previous comment carefully, I know the reasons to close a question

Answer (score 1):

May be it is not the best but its one way of doing this as in my opinion this effect looks difficult to achieve with `text-shadow`.

Here are the necessary steps:

1. Use `HTML5` `data-*` attribute to store the same text as in DOM node.
2. Use `:before` or `:after` pseudo element to draw this text below the normal text.
3. Apply css3  `scale()` transformation and other necessary styles.

```css
.text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 30px 110px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: skyblue;
  font-size: 0;
}

.text span:first-child {
  color: pink;
}

.text span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text span:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: scale(1.7);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  bottom: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}

.text span + span:before {
  left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span data-title="o">o</span>
  <span data-title="ferta">ferta</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, syntax for text-shadow is: `text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ff0000;`
First value is for x position.
Second value is for y position.
Third value is for radius and it's the size you are looking for! ;-)

If you try `text-shadow: 1px 1px 50px black;` you will have a very big shadow over the text.

Comment: When i'm using the third value the shadow is getting more blurry not bigger? Why is that?

Comment: this is wrong, the first is x offset, the second is y offset and the last is blur.  You cannot change the size with text shadow